# Clicking the search button in mobile chat should move focus to the search field

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

I've been using search functionality of mobile chat a little more often lately. When I tap the search icon I expect focus to move to the search field, which would in turn open the virtual keyboard.

It doesn't happen:

[image]

I propose setting the  focus on `input[type=search]` when the search button is clicked. I think it would be a nice UX improvement.